# IBM Watson Assistant: Access issues when using ngrok for webhook URL

Tags: node.js, webhooks, ibm-watson, ngrok, watson-assistant

Good morning everyone. I am developing an application that uses the watson assistant webhook by sending some parameters to a server, which analyzes the parameters and based on these sends a response to the application and to watson itself.

Well, it turns out that I was using ngrok to do this test by placing the parameters in watson, until a few days ago I couldn't (or it doesn't exactly let me) make the request.
[image]

Error
Cannot create property 'transactionId' on string ' Access Denied

## Access Denied

You don't have permission to access "http://us-south.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/rest/v2/skills/ on this server.

Reference    '

I have tried other applications that allow me to do the same work as ngrok, but I am new to this and it is very complicated. LOCALTUNNEL solved my problem temporarily, but later it didn't work anymore. I also tried with portmap.io, serveo, pagekite, smee.io among others and I still can't perform my requests.
I would really appreciate any help with my problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: What exactly do you try to accomplish? Where is the server for the webhook located?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: @data_henrik In my case, we have a backend to which we want to send data via webhooks. In order to develop/test the webhooks, we run the backend on localhost and have a "public" tunnel via ngrok. When entering the ngrok url into the webhook input at watson, we get the same error message as OP, even though the url is publicly accesible. Maybe this additional information could help you answer the question.